# asyncio : very strange handling of global variables within tasks

Tags: python, global-variables

if this function is run as a task in asyncio:

```
async def test():
    x = "strange"
    while True:
        def myfunc():
            global x
            x = "expected"
        myfunc()
        print("This is " + x)
        await asyncio.sleep(1)


loop.create_task(test())
loop.run_forever()
```

I would expect "This is expected" , same outcome as any normal python app... but instead.. it prints "This is strange"  ... why ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is not related to asyncio.

`global x` links `x` variable to module-level object, not to `test` function.

Use `nonlocal x` instead to make the code work as expected.